# Design tab not showing preview of layout, "missing classes"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

My Design tab is not showing a preview of my layout. The error shown in the Design tab is the following:

> **Missing classes**
>
> The following classes could not be found:
>
> - com.example.views.MyCustomView (*Fix Build Path*, *Edit XML*, *Create Class*)

I use `MyCustomView` as the root view in my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.views.MyCustomView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ... more layouts here ...   

    </com.example.views.MyCustomView>
```

Here is my `MyCustomView` class, which is located in `com.example.views`:

```
package com.example.views;

public class MyCustomView extends DrawerLayout {
    ... Lots of code ...
}
```

Why am I getting this error in the Design tab? How can I show the preview of the layout?

Answer (score 1):

You must complete a successful **Build** action any time you update a custom view class in order for it to display in the layout editor preview.

On top of that, sometimes Android Studio's preview caches information that will stop it from correctly previewing your custom views. This can be solved by going `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: I've tried Cleaning, Rebuilding, and Invalidating Caches/Restart. None of those helped. :/

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade my AndroidStudio to 4.1.x, then custom view rending error.
with operation`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.`, it works well.
But after complete `Build`,rending error again.
tried solutions:

1. In design view,change api level, not work.
2. click `Build` in design view, not work.
3. click `refresh` button in design view, not work.
4. upgrade `gralde` version and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.x`,it works